# I cant generate CUP parser and JFlex scanner in cmd

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-errors, jflex, cup

i'm new in compiler . i've read that i can generate xxx.flex file in cmd by this code :

> java JFlex.Main xxx.flex

but i got this error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class JFlex.Main

and for generating yyy.cup , i typed :

> java java_cup.Main yyy.cup

but i got this error too :

> Error: Could not find or load main class java_cup.Main

i confused ... what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are invoking

```
java JFlex.Main xxx.flex
```

You ask java to load the `JFlex.Main` class and passing `xxx.flex` as parameter. As you do not tell java where is that `JFlex.Main` class, java is searching it in its classpath, and if you did not add the JFlex jar file to the class path, it results in the error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class JFlex.Main
```

BTW, class names and namespaces are case-sensitive : in the JFlex jar file, the `Main` class is in the `jflex` directory, not `JFlex` so you need to invoke the `jflex.Main` class... unless you are using the a JFlex version prior to 1.5 where `JFlex` is legal.

To let java find the class:

- either change the system class path (with the environment variable `$CLASSPATH`- or `%CLASSPATH%` in windows)
- or just provide the location of the jar file the the `java` command with the `-cp` parameter

For example:

```
java -cp path/to/jflex-1.6.0.jar jflex.Main xxx.jflex
```

If the jar is in the current directory, you can just use

```
java -cp jflex-1.6.0.jar jflex.Main xxx.jflex
```

Or more simply, as it is an executable jar, you can omit the main class

```
java -jar jflex-1.6.0.jar xxx.jflex
```

Similarly, it seems that java is missing the CUP jar file while processing your `yyy.cup` file, you can fix it like for JFlex with

```
java -cp java-cup-11a.jar java_cup.Main yyy.cup
```

or

```
java -jar java-cup-11a.jar java_cup.Main yyy.cup
```